# Swift - append to array that is in an array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, append

I am writing a class that returns JSON data. I create an array of the type NSArray. To this Array I add arrays of the type String.

I later want to append strings to the array of type String that is within the array of type NSArray.

However it does not allow this, I have no idea why because the append function does work when appending NSArrays to the main array.

This is the entire class:

```
import Foundation

class JSON {
    struct Static {

        let hostname = "http://192.168.2.115:8888/tcn/";

        func getJSON(script:String, jsonMainElement:String, elements:[String]) -> [NSArray] {
            var returnObject = [NSArray]()

            let urlAsString = hostname + script;
            let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)!
            let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

            let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    println(error.localizedDescription);
                }
                var err: NSError?
                var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
                if (err != nil) {
                    println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)");
                }
                var i = 0;
                let arrayFromJson: [[String:String]] = jsonResult[jsonMainElement] as [[String:String]]
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    for item in arrayFromJson {
                        returnObject.append([String]());
                        for jsonObject in elements {
                            returnObject[i].append(item[jsonObject]!);
                            // ^ THIS LINE GIVES ERROR
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    if (arrayFromJson.count > 0) {
                        //k
                    }
                })

            })
            jsonQuery.resume()
            return returnObject;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention the error. It is: "Could not find member 'append'"

Comment: You can change the declaration of returnObject to [[AnyObjet]](), then it is a Swift array which has an append method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to define the array as containing a mutable array as below.

```
var returnObject = [NSMutableArray]()
```

You could also use a Swift 'sub' array, and define it more like this.

```
var returnObject = Array<Array<String>>()
```

Don't forget to update your return on the method.

```
func getJSON() -> Array<Array<String>>
```

[image: Array Playground]